# sliding window with tidyr nest

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I am using tidyr::nest to deliver a grouped_by table to function `boot` and `boot.ci` from  `boot` package in order to calculate mean and confidence interval for a non-parametric statistic.  This works fine for non-overlapping groups like below:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)
library(lubridate)
library(broom)
library(boot)

#toy example
set.seed(1)
Sys.setenv(TZ="America/Chicago")
df <- data.frame(date = mdy("01-01-2018")+ddays(sample(0:364,100,replace = T)),
                 score = sample(0:10,100,replace = T,prob=c(0.15,0.15,rep(0.15/7,7),0.25,0.3)))

# the statistic of interest
net_promoter_score <- function(data,col_name='score') {
  return(
    (sum(data[[col_name]]>=9,na.rm=TRUE)-
        sum(data[[col_name]]<=6,na.rm=TRUE))/sum(!is.na(data[[col_name]]))*100 
  )
}

# boot needs to resample the staistic by index
nps_boot <- function(d,i) net_promoter_score(d[i,])


#do NPS confidence intervals by month - this works fine!
by_month = df %>%
  mutate(month = lubridate::month(date,label=T,abbr=T)) %>%
  nest(-month) %>%
  mutate(boots = map(data, ~boot::boot(.x,nps_boot,R=4999)),
         CI = map(boots, ~boot::boot.ci(.x,conf=0.9)$bca),
         tidied_NPS = map(boots,broom::tidy),
         tidied_CI = map(CI,broom::tidy)
  ) %>%
  unnest(tidied_NPS,tidied_CI,.drop=T) %>%
  select(month,mean=statistic,CI10=V4,CI90=V5)
by_month %>% head
 A tibble: 6 x 4
  month   mean   CI10  CI90
  <ord>  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
1 Apr     0    -100    33.3
2 May     6.67  -46.7  33.3
3 Jul    60    -100    60  
4 Nov   -20     -80    20  
5 Mar   -11.1   -66.7  33.3
6 Dec     0    -100    50
```

But I would like to do this for a sliding window - kind of like a moving average except I would like to use a different statistic to slide over.  I can do this with `lapply` but I would like to use `tidyverse`.

```
#do 50-sample sliding window.  I would like to solve this with tidyverse
window_size = 50
results = lapply(1:(nrow(df)-window_size), function(x) {
  boot_df = df %>% arrange(date) %>% slice(x:(x+window_size-1))
  boot = boot::boot(boot_df,nps_boot,R=999)
  CI = boot.ci(boot,conf=0.9)$bca[4:5]
  return(c(x,mean(boot$t),CI))
})
by_slide = as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, results)) %>%
  select(date=V1,mean=V2,CI10=V3,CI90=V4) %>%
  mutate(date = mdy("01-01-2018")+ddays((window_size %/% 2)+date))
by_slide %>% head
        date     mean      CI10 CI90
1 2018-01-27 15.40541  -8.00000   38
2 2018-01-28 15.94194  -8.00000   36
3 2018-01-29 15.83383  -8.00000   36
4 2018-01-30 15.24525  -8.00000   38
5 2018-01-31 15.79780 -10.00000   36
6 2018-02-01 15.82583 -10.92218   36
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `purrr::map_dfr()`:

```
results <- purrr::map_dfr(1:(nrow(df)-window_size), function(x) {
  boot_df = df %>% arrange(date) %>% slice(x:(x+window_size-1))
  boot = boot::boot(boot_df,nps_boot,R=999)
  CI = boot.ci(boot,conf=0.9)$bca[4:5]
  list(date = boot_df$date[1], 
       mean = mean(boot$t), 
       ci_lo = CI[1], 
       ci_hi = CI[2])
}) 

results
# A tibble: 50 x 4
   date        mean  ci_lo ci_hi
   <date>     <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
 1 2018-01-05  15.6  -8       38
 2 2018-01-09  16.3  -8       36
 3 2018-01-22  16.2 -10       36
 4 2018-01-23  15.6 -10       36
 5 2018-01-26  15.2 -10       36
 6 2018-01-31  16.5 -10       36
 7 2018-02-06  19.7  -4.75    40
 8 2018-02-09  19.5  -8       40
 9 2018-02-14  16.3 -10       36
10 2018-02-15  16.1 -10       36
# … with 40 more rows
```

Then you can use `results` directly in computing `by_slide`:

```
by_slide = results %>%
  mutate(date = mdy("01-01-2018") + ddays(window_size %/% 2))
```

Although I admit I don't understand how adding `date` in the `ddays` duration object works, that doesn't seem to come out with your provided output.  But I'm assuming that's a syntax issue - separate from your question about how to replace `lapply`.

Comment: you are correct.  the date is pointing to the middle of the window but that's not material to the question.  You got it done with map_df but I guess I expected a more group_by -> nest -> map -> tidy -> unnest workflow. Thanks. Let's see if there any other ideas out there.